# Variability and mean

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, variability

I am working with future climate change scenarios and I end up with this question.

Is it expected from a statistical perspective that a change in the mean goes hand-in-hand with a change in the variance? In other words, by increasing the mean we always increase the variability?

Comment: Sure, assuming you underlying distribution is log-normal.

Comment: This may or may not be the case, depending on what quantity we're talking about, and all the relevant knowledge that goes into it. From a purely statistical perspective, without taking into account the meaning of the measurement, model and its components, nothing can be said. As the comment by @user2974951 says, once we make statistical assumptions, these have implications - still we can only justify such assumptions from subject matter knowledge and/or data analysis.

Comment: *How* exactly do you conceive of the process of "changing the mean"?  This sounds like a question about climate change rather than statistics.